# Node Module Path Execution Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows

```
$ npm install -g static-server
C:\Users\Stuart's\AppData\Roaming\npm\static-server -> C:\Users\Stuart's\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\static-server\bin\static-server.js
+ static-server@2.2.1
added 13 packages from 6 contributors in 1.238s

Stuart's@Stuarts-PC MINGW64 ~/Documents/GitHub/PIES-Network/dapp (master)
$ static-server
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\c\Users\Stuart's\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\static-server\bin\static-server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

clearly "C:\c\User.." is not a correct path to my node modules directory. I have checked my local paths and everything looks fine. Any help is appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This looks a lot like you have accidentally created a directory called `C:\c\Users\Stuart's\AppData\Roaming\npm` wherein is located the file `static-server.cmd`. You have a path variable pointing there also somehow.

When `static-server` is invoked control is passed to the `static-server.cmd` batch file at this incorrect location.

`node 'C:\c\Users\Stuart's\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\static-server\bin\static-server.js`

But `static-server.js` is located as per your install at:

`C:\Users\Stuart's\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\static-server\bin\static-server.js`.

In these circumstances you will get exactly the errors shown.

It could be some variation on this and I am happy to help further, but step 1 is to check above because for sure the incorrect path parameter is being passed to node (which of course load and executes `static-server.js`).

**EDIT:** Here are some further tests:

1. Search for all instances of "static-server" on your hard disc.
   Trying to do this with Explorer will take a long time.
   The best and fastest way is to download a tool called UltraSeach.

   Here are the search results from my PC ( I created the extra C:\c directory for test purposes).

[image]

2. Check for multiple versions of static-server.cmd or other executable file of that name.
3. Using a text editor (like notepad) open each `static-server.cmd` file and add these ECHO commands at the top 
   (ie before the line staret with `@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (`

   `ECHO "File 1 executing"`

   `ECHO "%~dp0"`

   `PAUSE`

If more than one version put "File 2", "File 3" etc.

4. Now type `static-server` at a command prompt and it should 
   Echo the message "File n executing"
   Echo the directory it is executing from
   Wait for you to press a key to continue.....

   Note the directory it is executing from (call it \CURRENT say)
5. You can see from static-server.cmd that it then starts node 
   and tried to execute \CURRENT\node_modules\static-server\bin\static-server.js

   In your case its not finding static-server.js where node expects to find it.
6. Look back to search results in step 1 and see where static-server.js is actually located.
   Compare this to where node expects to find it in step 5.

Your problem is either that:
The static-server.cmd being executed is located in the wrong place OR
static-server.js is located at the wrong place.

7. Here is an additional test. Open a command window and navigate to the directory which has static-server.js. As per the screen-shot it is at `C:\Users\Brendan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\static-server\bin` in my case.

Then type `node static-server.js`. This bypasses the `static-server.cmd` file altogether, and should start the server. Worked in my case.

Let me know how you go!

Comment: I have searched my computer for any folder under c/c/,  hidden or visible and nothing comes up. I have redownloaded node twice and restarted my computer. I have deleted all path variables that relate to the node. What else can I do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Ok this is solvable but you need to make some checks and I will edit the reply. If you see me on line then open a chat - which would be quicker.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for this guide, I really appreciate your time. I have been working on my other computer putting off the time until I have to debug this issue. I will let you know ASAP once I try to get node back and running on my windows machine

Comment: OK no worries. Its definitely fixable.